# if G is a simple connected graph that contains no P4 then diam(G) is equal or less than 2

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

G is a simple graph which is connected .
it has no induced subgraph as P4 ( a path with 4 vertices ) .
 prove that diam(G) is equal or less than 2 .
consider that : diam(G)=max{d(u,v)|u,v are vertices of G}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose your graph has diameter at least $3$.
Then there are two vertices $x, y$ at distance at least $3$.
Take a shortest path between $x$ and $y$.  What can you say about this path ?